# Is there a way to allow mutability on @apollo/client 3.0

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to upgrade to @apollo/client 3.0.
Previously, it allowed me to mutate the data that I receive when I do a query.
Now, I'm getting this kind of error:

`TypeError: Cannot add property mediaTargetsByMediaType, object is not extensible`.

PS: A deep clone might not working on my case. I'm using a grid that relies on keeping the same reference between the apollo store and the data I'm mutating.